# Grap API - How can I update email address for a Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

with v2.2 I can retrieve an email address for a page by:

{page-id}/?fields=emails

But I can not find how to update it by a post request? Does any one have any idea?

Big thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t think you can change the email with the Graph API, check out the docs for all the things you can change: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page

Take a look at the footnotes: "indicates fields that can be added or updated via API."

...and check out the section about "Publishing and Updating" with more information and code examples.